# Mpdf barcode component leaves trailing angle bracket

Tags: php, mpdf

When using Mpdf's barcode component, it leaves trailing angle bracket.

How can I remove it?

```php
$pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$pdf->WriteHTML('<barcode code="9315517229426" />');
$pdf->Output();
```

Output:

[image: Bracode with '>']

I'm using Mpdf version 8.0.0

Comment: just FYI, it is part of the barcode specification itself (i.e. EAN-13), not a typo or something. more : [International_Article_Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mPDF leaves the `>` character according to EAN:

> […] additionally a right ">" indicator is used to indicate a "Quiet Zone" that is necessary for barcode scanners to work properly.

It is not an error, it is completely intentional and a correct part of the barcode.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number